# How to add another Frame to the Frame

Tags: java, awt, panel, frame

I have to use `Frame` not `JFrame`. I have to use `BorderLayout`.
I created a

```
class A extends Frame{}

class B extends Frame{}
```

and I woule like to add instance of class A into class B but what I get is another window. I want to make that A is "subframe" to B it is inside of it.

```
class B{  
...
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Panel p = new Panel();
        a = new A();
        p.add(a);
        add(a, BorderLayout.CENTER);
....
}
```

Comment: Use a `CardLayout`.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  This is mentioned around every 8 hours on SO. *"I have to use `Frame` not `JFrame`."*  Why?

Comment: I have to use `BorderLayout` did not supsect this kind of answer was coming so I didn't write it.

Comment: *"I have to use `BorderLayout`"*  ***Why?***

Comment: Because stupid teacher of my student said so. Sorry I am angry I understand stupidity of that demand.

Comment: OK - a `Panel` with a `CardLayout` can be put inside a constraint of a `BorderLayout` (or vice-versa).  But do me a favor & drag your teacher, kicking & screaming if need be, into this millennium.  Most Java GUI developers have never used AWT, and those of us who did, have largely forgotten the details.

Comment: Also, now I notice.  The code should not `extend` frame.  Just use an instance of one.